# writing json data to request stream

Tags: .net, spring, byte

I am writing a Spring RESTful web service which is suppose to accept data from another application. Inside the service I have annotated method with @RequestBody so that I can receive json data in the Java Objects (using Jackson). Application on the other end is implemented in .NET and it is setting byte array before calling my REST service.

Problem is, that I am not able to receive data inside my service method. Though my service runs fine when I tested it by sending JSON data in plain text.

When I asked developer of the other application he said, in .NET text data can not be set in request stream and only byte array can be set. I am not sure if this is correct? and what is the way to convert byte array data to json string before it reaches to my service method and converted to java objects.

Answer (score 1):

I used RestSharp from the nuget installer.

On reading the last paragraph, are you trying to send text data to a GET method?

If so, I ended up using POST method to simulate GET method that had an object required to send over as a parameter.

Perhaps this is what you need to do?

Comment: Yes text data to a POST method. He is not setting parameters but sending directly in the stream.

Comment: When I was trying to send text up, I had used [FromBody] as Object, and then I was able to use the body in the Post.

Answer (score 0):

So we had reached to a point where .Net application was sending binary data in request stream and I was able to read it using httpServletRequest.getReader();